# Retrieve value from socket event

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I currently, have a `node.js` running with **Socket IO**. And I am listening to something like: `+level` and when it is retrieved from a client, update an object.

```
socket.on("+level", async (data) => { console.log(`Level: ${data}`);  player.updateLevel(data) })
```

On fortunately, this does not work. I am using Postman set it to Socket.IO and then I am sending like this: `+level 10`.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set event name to `+level` here:

[image: event name]

And send `10` as an arg in Postman.

See the GIF here for more info:
https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-socket-io/#sending-events